# Click on image not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, onmouseover

For some reason I cannot click on this image to show the fancybox if I have "onmouseover" as a parameter:

```
<area onmouseover="toggleOverlay('SteWoz',1);" id="locSteWoz" alt="Test" class="fancybox" coords="24,51,236,244" href="http://www.google.com" rel="iframe" shape="rect" title="Test">
```

**EDIT:** This is what toggleOverlay does:

```
<script>
    function toggleOverlay(name, newState){
        var element = 'imgOverlay' + name;
        var newDisplay

        if (newState == 0) {newDisplay = 'none'}
        if (newState == 1) {newDisplay = 'block'}           

        document.getElementById(element).style.display = newDisplay;
        //document.getElementById(element).style.z-index = '5';

            $(element).hide().fadeIn(4000);
    }
</script>
```

If I remove "onmouseover" it works fine. How can I "fix" this?

James

Comment: What does the `toggleOverlay` function do ?

Comment: show us the click handler please

Comment: There's not enough informations but I think some DOM element is getting over your area and getting the `.click` event.

Comment: is there a way I can make the overlay not respond to any clicks so that the image below can be clicked?

Comment: Is `element` overlaying the image used as map?

Answer (score 0):

**First**, this line :

```
$(element).hide().fadeIn(4000);
```

... doesn't really do anything because at this point `element` still need a proper sign (either `#` or `.`) to define the selector so in this case should be :

```
$("#" + element).hide().fadeIn(1000);
```

**Second**, if you are overlaying another image over the image that uses the image `map`, what I assume you are doing like in this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hCu5b/)**,

... then there is nothing you can do to "***make the overlay not respond to any clicks so that the image below can be clicked***".

What you could do however, is to make the *overlay* image to use the same image `map` as the image below so, within your `toggleOverlay()` function, you could tweak this line

```
$("#" + element).hide().fadeIn(1000);
```

... into this

```
$("#" + element).hide().fadeIn(1000).attr("usemap", "#Map");
```

... assuming that your html looks like

```
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area onmouseover="toggleOverlay('SteWoz',1);" id="locSteWoz" class="fancybox" shape="square" coords="0,0,415,319" href="{target}" title="title" alt="alt" />
</map>
```

... otherwise use the corresponding ID of the `map` tag.

See **[updated JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hCu5b/1/)**